# add more selected item, not replace selected item in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

i found this code in internet

http://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/owhq5jat/

When i select new item, old item replaced by new item.

How can add more item, not replace when i click "dropdown list" ?

Thank you

```
<select id="select1">
<option></option>
<option>AAA</option>
<option>BBB</option>
<option>CCC</option>
<option>DDD</option>
<option>EEE</option>
</select>
<textarea style="height:150px;width:150px" id="t1"></textarea>
<textarea style="height:150px;width:150px" id="t2"></textarea>

<script>
$("#select1").change(function () {
    $("#t1").val($(this).find(':selected').text());
});

$("#select1").change(function () {
    $("#t2").val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will **append selected value in textarea using comma(,)** sperator.

```js
$("#select1").change(function () {
  if($("#t1").val() != ""){
    $("#t1").val($("#t1").val() + ", " + $(this).find(':selected').text());
    $("#t2").val($("#t2").val() + ", " + $(this).val());
  } else {
    $("#t1").val($(this).find(':selected').text());
    $("#t2").val($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option></option>
    <option>AAA</option>
    <option>BBB</option>
    <option>CCC</option>
    <option>DDD</option>
    <option>EEE</option>
</select>
<textarea style="height:150px;width:150px" id="t1"></textarea>
<textarea style="height:150px;width:150px" id="t2"></textarea>
```